# Regex not working on chrome but works in safari

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a code that at a point asks executes following code snippet:

```
new RegExp('^(?:[^\n]{0,30}(?:\n?|\n)){0,15}[^\n]{0,30}$').test("123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n1234567890123456789012345qweqweqwea\nqweqweqwe\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n123456789012345678901234567890a\n")
```

The above expression when executed using safari gives result as `false` as expected. While onto Chrome it makes the tab hang. Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue on Chrome?

Comment: Above issue is also reproducible with firefox

Comment: Why should it be false? [it works at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oBB6zk/1) it also works with php, perl. I think safari is wrong.